# Prove that a strictly decreasing function from $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is one-to-one

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would like to prove that a strictly decreasing function from $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is one-to-one.

We want to show that show that $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $ a = b$ for all $a, b \in \Bbb R$.

One proof I saw online was as follows (although I did the same proof using contrapositive technique), but I just want to get better understanding as to why he did the proof as follows:

Proof:

Since the function is strictly decreasing, it means that if  $ x \lt y \implies f(x) \gt f(y)$. To proof that it's one-to-one function, we need to prove that if $f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$.

Let $f(a) = f(b)$.

**Case 1**:  Consider when $a \lt b$, then this implies that $f(a) \gt f(b)$ since $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing. This implies that $f(a) \ne f(b) \therefore a\ge b $.

**Case 2**: Consider when $a \gt b$, then this implies that $f(a) \lt f(b)$ since $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing. This implies that $f(a) \ne f(b) \therefore a = b $.

Questions:

1. It seems the proof that was used in the question is proof by cases, was not it?
2. Why it was assumed, in Case 1, that $f(a) = f(b)$ although what is given in the question is that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing?
3. Why it was concluded ,in Case 1, that since $f(a) \ne f(b) \therefore a\ge b $?
4. I assume that it was finally concluded that $\therefore a = b $ is because no other scenarios left as to why $f(a) = f(b)$ except by equality of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: As you note, to prove $f$ is injective, it suffices to show that $f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$. The proof *assumes* $f(a)=f(b)$, then deduces that $a<b$ and $a>b$ are both impossible (so yes, I guess technically the proof splits into two cases). Hence we must have $a=b$, proving what we want.

Comment: @jlammy. Thank you. How he can assume such a thing, also this is a conclusion that we want to show and it's not given in the assumption?

Comment: The definition of one-to-one is that *if* $f(a)=f(b)$, *then* we must have $a=b$. So the obvious way to prove $f$ is one-to-one is to suppose that $f(a)=f(b)$ is true, then deduce that $a=b$ must be true.

Comment: @jlammy. Thank you. So we can start by assuming anything as long as it will lead us to the result in mind in the conclusion (in this case one-to-one), is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: Here's an example which might help you understand the logic better. Suppose you want to show that if person $X$ and person $Y$ have the same fingerprints, then in fact $X$ and $Y$ are the same person. Then you only care about cases where two people $X$ and $Y$ have the same fingerprints. This is why we "assume" that $X$ and $Y$ have the same fingerprints -- if they don't, then they are irrelevant to the point we are trying to prove.

Comment: Question $3$:  since $a<b$ led to a contradiction, it follows that $a\ge b$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. Thank you. So the proof uses proof by cases and proof by contradiction at the same time?

Comment: Yes, @Avra, there's a contradiction in the cases where $a<b$ and $a>b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof really overcomplicates it. Rather, prove the contrapositive:

$$x \neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)$$

This is then easy, because either $x < y$ or $y < x$ and thus either $f(x) < f(y)$ or $f(y) < f(x)$. Hence, $f(x) \neq f(y)$ when $x\neq y$.

Comment: Thank you. I mentioned in the question that this is how I did it, but as you said, the proof above overcomplicates it.

Comment: Can you please summarize in simple words what the proof above is trying to do without fancy math symbols ?

Comment: @Avra Sure. I think in the comments this was already explained just fine? But I would focus on the geometric aspect of the question: is it geometrically obvious to you that a strictly increasing/decreasing function is injective?

Comment: Yes, but a ceiling function could be strictly increasing/decreasing, but it's not one to one and thus not injective.

Comment: @Avra A ceiling function is not STRICTLY increasing: for example the ceiling function evaluated in $1/3$ and $2/3$ is equal.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I got down voted? This is not fair as I did all my best to follow the guideline of the asking question.

Comment: @Avra I don't know either why you got downvoted. I upvoted to compensate this :)